# How to add OLEDB provider to continuous integration build on tfs?

Tags: build, tfs, oledb, provider, continuous

every time I start a build on TFS I get a error message that the OLEDB provider is missing on the local machine:

Test method BookLibrary.UnitTest.DatabaseCommunicationTest.AddBookTest threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Is there any option to add the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider to a TFS continuous build?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging into the build machine and installing [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: No. I do not have access to the build machine. Is there another way to run these test without installing the Mirosoft Access DB Enginge 2010?

Comment: No, those specific tests require it.  You could filter out any that require it and not run them on the build server though.